# Getting the colour of bar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have constructed a bar chart in matplotlib and its embedded in wxpython.
At the moment i have been able to get the points by using `event.artist.get_bbox().get_points()`. I want to get the colour of the particular bar. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want an rgba tuple?

If so, just use `event.artist.get_facecolor()`.

As a quick example (seeing as you seem to be dealing with pick events...):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_pick(event):
    print event.artist.get_facecolor()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(range(10), range(10), picker=5)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)

plt.show()
```